# Animating/Transitioning between 3 activities cleanly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, activity-transition

I have 3 activities - A, B and C.

Activity A starts B for activity result. I use overridePendingTransition when B closes, giving it a sexy finish effect and returning to A. Then A makes sure the result is good and starts C with a (different) sexy open effect using overridePendingTransition again.

The problem:

C's overridePendingTransition is firing way to fast and screwing up B's finish effect.

The question:

Is there a listener I can use to make sure B's transition has finished before starting C's?

Comment: Just a dumb question: have you tried waiting for onResume? You are supposed to receive that only when the Activity is ready for input. Haven't tried it, so I don't know if it will work.

Comment: I did but  resume is firing at the start of the animation, resulting in the same  problem.

Answer (score 0):

No way as far as i know to listen directly. I have had this issue before and the best way i have been able to this is just add a delay using a handler to starting your c activity so b has time to finish. It will look something like this

```
//in onactivityresult or where you are starting c now
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
           startactivity(intentc);             
      }}, 1000); //this will start it in 1 second
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid :(

Comment: @DavidZafrani haha well if you find an answer let me know what it is.